# Job Queues and the JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript

Node.js exposes `process.nextTick`, which ensures that the callback supplied is invoked upon return of control to the runtime. This runs the risk of "starving the event loop", by preventing evaluation of jobs on the Job Queue.

Internet Explorer exposes `setImmediate` which, as far as I can tell, uses a separate Job Queue and some logic so that the items are popped off the queue once per loop iteration, precluding "event loop starvation".

`requestAnimationFrame` maintains its own queue of callbacks that will be invoked one after the other, immediately before the VBLANK of the graphics subsystem.

Is it correct to say that the JavaScript runtime coordinates the running of jobs from *various* queues by supplying them to the event loop for execution at times determined by algorithms specific to those queues, and that in some sense what is going on is more complicated that a single event loop being served by a single Job Queue?

Comment: Is it possible to refer to "the" JavaScript runtime in that statement? As you note in the question, this seems to be implementation-specific, and I don't think any aspect of it is covered in the ECMAScript specs.

Comment: The `requestAnimationFrame` list isn't quite like a separate task queue: all `requestAnimationFrame` run one after the other, run by one single task in the task queue. So, your task queue could look like `[some-task], [other-task], [execute-all-rAF-callbacks-in-sequence-task], [other-task]`. (http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#processingmodel)

Comment: @apsillers, okay, so the `requestAnimationFrame` queue may not be relevant. Is the `requestanimationframe` subsystem just another client of the Job Queue or does it have some kind of special privileges?

Comment: @BenAston Well, the [W3C spec does say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#queue-a-task), "a user agent could have one task queue for mouse and key events... and another for everything else. The user agent could then give keyboard and mouse events preference over other tasks three quarters of the time, keeping the interface responsive..." So, it's *possible* that the browser could have a dedicated task queue for animation tasks that is populated only on visual refresh and has 100% priority over other queues. However, I don't know that any browser actually does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the queue works and if there is more than one is implementation-specific, but it is possible to have more than one queue and special rules that state which job from which queue is going to be run first.